# How to replace an entire file using FileManager

Tags: ios, swift, caching, nsfilemanager

Let's say I have an `UIImage` cached in my Cache folder:
`/.../Cache/Image Cache/<firstImage.id>`

Now I want this folder to only ever have 10 image cached at a time, so if a new one comes in I want to take a file and replace the *entire* file and not just the contents of it. I.e.
`/.../Cache/Image Cache/<firstImage.id>` becomes
`/.../Cache/Image Cache/<secondImage.id>`.

As far as I can tell, `replaceItem(at:withItemAt:backupItemName:options:` only replaces the contents of the file but the file name remains the same. And I'm not too sure what `replaceItem(at:withItemAt:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:)` does even though it might be what I'm looking for (I don't know what an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURL?>?` was but it sounded dangerous so I decided to leave it alone, specially since it has the word "unsafe" in it).

Is there a straightforward way of doing using an in-built function or is manually deleting the old file and adding the new file the best way? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Removing the existing file and creating a new file *is* the straightforward way if the file names are different.

Comment: @MartinR Is there no built-in function for this like `replace(...)`? I assumed there would be one considering it seems like such a common thing to do.

Comment: If you want only a single file at all times, why don't you use a fixed file name? Then replacing it is all you have to do.

Comment: @MartinR Oh I actually need 10 files at max I just said 1 for simplicity sake but I'll change my question to reflect that. But is there any built-in function for replacing the entire file (including the file name)?

Comment: No, there isn't.